# Android -Json httpRequest Time out Connection

Tags: android, json, connection, timeout, httprequest

How to make a Connection Timeout, when I do a httpRequest? I return to the previous activity? For my apilcacion is blocked by a firewall, and I can make some time to not be able to connect to the server, I return to the previous activity and display a Toast telling me no internet connection?

This is part of my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_list, "GET",
                params);

        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                daftar_rs = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DAFTAR_RS);

                for (int i = 0; i < daftar_rs.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = daftar_rs.getJSONObject(i); 
//Continue here with a process to show a listview...
```

When there is no internet connection the application closes completely showing an error, anyone know how I can fix it? Thank you very much! Greetings teachers!

Comment: please see my answer, if you want to use `HttpClient` to retrieve the json string I could post more example code

Comment: @lelloman I want to use HttpClient, and I want if connection is reffused I return to the previous activity and I display a Toast "Connection Failed"

Comment: @lelloman I think it's more like a ConnectException what I use, because if no internet available, but if the application can not connect to the internet, for example is blocked by a firewall

Comment: gulp...so you don't need to check for connectivity, btw that could come in handy some day...please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check if you have access to internet you can use something like

```
public boolean connesso() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

for the connection timeout I use an httpclient to make the request like so, you can handle also socket timeout

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeout1 = 1000*10;
int timeout2 = 1000*10;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout1);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout2);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

String jsonString = "";
HttpGet request;
try {
    request = new HttpGet(new URI(url));

    request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Android");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        jsonString = out.toString();
    }

    }catch(ConnectException e){             
    // handle your exception here, maybe something like
        Toast.makeText(context,"Error!",5000).show();
        finish(); // if your are within activity class, otherwise call finish on your activity          

    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
// etc...
```